# transforming a Ricatti equation into a generalised Ricatti equation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

C̶o̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶ ̶R̶i̶c̶a̶t̶t̶i̶ ̶e̶q̶u̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶m̶

$$ y' + y^2 = S(x), \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)$$

w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶$̶S̶(̶x̶)̶$̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶e̶r̶o̶m̶o̶r̶p̶h̶i̶c̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶$̶y̶$̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶l̶e̶x̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶d̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶ ̶D̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶i̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶u̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶$̶(̶1̶)̶$̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶-̶w̶r̶i̶t̶t̶e̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶g̶e̶n̶e̶r̶a̶l̶i̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶R̶i̶c̶a̶t̶t̶i̶ ̶e̶q̶u̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶
̶
$$u' = P(x) + Q(x)u + R(x)u^2, \qquad \qquad \qquad(2)$$

w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶$̶P̶,̶ ̶Q̶,̶ ̶R̶$̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶n̶o̶n̶-̶z̶e̶r̶o̶ ̶m̶e̶r̶o̶m̶o̶r̶p̶h̶i̶c̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶?̶
̶

**Edit:** M̶y̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶t̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶[̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶p̶a̶p̶e̶r̶]̶[̶1̶]̶,̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶w̶a̶r̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶(̶2̶)̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶(̶1̶)̶.̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶u̶g̶g̶l̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶a̶k̶e̶s̶ ̶(̶1̶)̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶(̶2̶)̶.̶

**Edit 2:** Ignore the previous remarks. I am currently looking for a transformation that will take a general second order equation of the form

$$a(x) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+c(x)y=0$$

where $a(x),b(x),c(x)$ are complex-valued, meromorphic functions into the form of $(2)$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Setting $u = y$ with $P = S$, $Q \equiv 0$, and $R \equiv -1$ you have what you desire. What am I missing?

Comment: @WillieWong sorry, my mistake. I'll edit the question details now.

Comment: The paper that you mentioned wants the functions to be (a) defined on the complex plane (b) meromorphic. You want functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that are smooth. Why do you think you can get an answer?

Comment: Furthermore, the normal form transformation is clearly non-unique, so it seems strange to ask for just "any" inverse map...

Comment: @WillieWong I am not actually certain I can get an answer, so I've actually adjusted my expectations to that of meromorphic functions. Also, for my purposes it is not necessary for the inverse map to be unique. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @WillieWong I edited the question, once more.

Comment: Both the forward and reverse transformation between the Riccati and a second order linear equation can be found on the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the wikipedia page for Ricatti equation has the answer, and it is covered in all ode textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation $y = -R(x) + s(x) u$ takes (1) to (2) with
$$\eqalign{P(x) &= {\frac {  s \left( x \right)^{2}+s'  \left( x \right) -S \left( x \right) }{R \left( x \right) }}
\cr
Q(x) &= -2 s(x)-\frac{R'(x)}{R(x)}}$$